# Show that $x^r = 1$ has exactly one solution for $x \in \mathbb{R} - \{0,1\}$, $r\in \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$

Tags: number-theory

I want to show that the two solutions to $x^r=1$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $r\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ are of the form $1^m$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $-1^2$. How do we show that there are no other solutions?

Comment: The polynomial $x^r-1$ has $r$ complex roots. There are at most $2$ real roots, viewing the circle in the complex plane. $x=1$ is always a root, but $-1$ only for $r$ even.

Comment: Do you allow both $x$ and $r$ to change at the same time (then each solution is a _pair_ of numbers) or fix $r$ and solve for $x$ (then each solution is _one_ number)?

Comment: You can restrict $r$ to natural numbers because when $r$ is negative, $r=-|r|$, you have $x^{-|r|}=1$ is equivalent with $1=x^{|r|}$ by multiplying with $x^{|r|}$

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $x^n-1$ factors uniquely in the algebraic closure of $\Bbb R$, the field of complex numbers $\Bbb C$, and the factors are $x-e^{2\pi i k/n}$, where $k=0,\ldots,n-1$.
As said by Dietrich Burde, there are at most 2 real roots. To see this, consider the even and odd case of $n$. A drawing of the $n$-th roots of unity in the unit circle would be helpful.